# how to create a new empty array column in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create a new column with each item as an empty array in dataframe,
for example, the dataframe is like:

`-`Index  Name
 `-`0       Mike
 `-`1        Tom
 `-`2       Lucy

I want to create a new column, make it like:

`-`Index Name1 Scores
 `-`0     Mike  []
 `-`1     Tom   []
 `-`2     Lucy  []

Because I need to append values in the arrays in the new column. How should I code?

Answer (score 5):

Solution using just python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Mike', 'Tom', 'Lucy']})
df['Scores'] = [[]] * df.shape[0]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Name Scores
0  Mike     []
1   Tom     []
2  Lucy     []
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using [***np.empty***](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [0,1,2], 'Name': ['Mike', 'Tom', 'Lucy']})
df['Scores'] = pd.np.empty((len(df), 0)).tolist()
print(df)
```

The output:

```
   Index  Name Scores
0      0  Mike     []
1      1   Tom     []
2      2  Lucy     []
```

`(len(df), 0)` - tuple representing given shape of a new array